# Why is my SELECT with a subquery and JOINs so slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery, innodb

This query takes 10 seconds to complete. But when I manually perform the subquery and change the `t1.id` restriction to that list, it's done in 0.00 seconds. What can I do to let MySQL execute the query quicker?

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
FROM t1, t2, t3
WHERE  t1.t2id = t2.id AND t1.t3id = t3.id
AND t1.id IN ( SELECT id FROM t4 WHERE blah = 123 )
```

Also, why is this happening? I suppose MySQL joins all three tables in some way before filtering on t1.id.

t1, t2 and t3 contain 3000, 15 and 80 rows, respectively. The subquery returns 2-10 rows.

Comment: try `explain select ...` and using explicit joins like `inner join ...`

Comment: @juergend from the comment score you seem to be right, but joining t2 and t3 using explicit `INNER JOIN` doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Use `explain` to see the execution plan of your query. Then you can see where it consumes that much time.

Comment: Joining t1 and t2, or t1 and t3 with INNER JOIN will change nothing. `FROM t1, t2, t3` is the same as using `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @juergend Sorry, I'm not very experienced with this. I can see that two parts contain a thousands of rows and that they're "using where" without keys. I still don't understand why that is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the query without subquery:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
FROM t1, t2, t3, (SELECT id FROM t4 WHERE blah = 123) AS t4
WHERE  t1.t2id = t2.id AND t1.t3id = t3.id
AND t1.id=t4.id
```

Be sure you have indexes on the fields used in the `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 2):

try to use the "INNER JOIN" rather than "IN" function.
This way your sql instruction will be more performative.

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t3.col3
FROM ((t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t2id = t2.id) INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.t3id = t3.id) INNER JOIN t4 ON t1.id = t4.id
WHERE t4.blah = 123
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run `EXPLAIN` over your statement, you may see that MySql has created a temporary table on disk: this often happens if the data within an inline select (your `IN` term) is sufficiently large.

In a nutshell:

a) use `EXPLAIN` to see what's going on in the database (and to see how this behaviour changes with increased data)

b) avoid inline subqueries if you can

c) remember that MySql only has a nested loop join algorithm at its disposal (other DBs use Hash join- and merge-join algorithms too) so you may see "less" parsing going on for smaller data sets, but a sudden drop off when you reach a tipping point.